# Whether to use distinct in a derived query to join a table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

need a small help regarding a query. For example, following are my two tables with the data

```
declare @table1 table (id int, column1 int)
declare @table2 table (id int, column2 int, column3 int)

insert into @table1 (id, column1) values (1, 10)
insert into @table1 (id, column1) values (2, 20)
insert into @table1 (id, column1) values (3, 30)

insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (1, 100, 8)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (1, 200, 7)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (1, 300, 6)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (1, 300, 5)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (2, 400, 4)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (2, 500, 3)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (3, 600, 2)
insert into @table2 (id, column2, column3) values (3, 700, 1)

--select * from @table1
--select * from @table2

-- Query 1
select t1.id, count(*) RecCount from @table1 t1 join (select distinct id, column2 from @table2) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id

-- Query 2
select t1.id, count(*) RecCount from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

From based on the above queries, can I get below output

```
id  RecCount
 1   3
 2   2
 3   2
```

From above queries, query 2 will not return expected output, Can you please let me know whether my query 1 will return the correct output or not. Please let me know is it proper to use distinct in a derived query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got 4 records in table 2 with ID 1. Why would you expect a count to give 3?

If you want to count the number of different values in column2 for each column, do

```
select t1.id, count(distinct column2) RecCount 
from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

Although in this instance, the join is not required, and

```
select id, count(distinct column2) RecCount 
from @table2 
group by id
```

would suffice.

Comment: I need three records output as thats the requirement and I also need the first table to be joined because I have two conditions on it. Can you please explain me the distinct inside count in first query.

Comment: @Harsha As the syntax suggests, it "Counts" the "Distinct" occurrences of the field (Column2)